# How can you enable "Use secure credentials" from the shell

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, security, adb

On the ICS ROM I'm using, the option to enable the secure credentials is missing from the menu, but the sub system seems to be there since Keystore Locker can communicate with it.

So does anybody know how I can enable/initialize secure credential storage from an `adb` shell?